# Disable dependency to libssp library?

Tags: embedded-linux, avahi, ssp

I am compiling avahi 0.6.27 for an embedded system with tinycore v3

I want to remove the dependency to the library ssp (stack smashing protection). For this I use the option `--disable-stack-protector` and compile. When running avahi-daemon still gives me error for library ssp:

> / usr / local / sbin / avahi-daemon: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libssp.so.0: can not open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

Do I have to add one more option or can not remove the dependency?

I am compiling using ubuntu 10.04

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --localstatedir=/var --with-distro=none --disable-stack-protector --disable-qt3 --disable-qt4 --disable-gdbm --disable-mono --with-avahi-user=tc --with-avahi-group=staff --with-avahi-priv-access-group=staff --with-autoipd-user=tc --with-autoipd-group=staff --disable-gtk3  --disable-nls --disable-glib --disable-gobject --disable-introspection --disable-gtk --disable-gtk3 --disable-dbus --disable-dbm --disable-gdbm --enable-libdaemon --disable-python --disable-pygtk --disable-python-dbus --disable-monodoc --disable-autoipd --disable-doxygen-doc --disable-doxygen-dot --disable-doxygen-man --disable-doxygen-rtf --disable-doxygen-xml --disable-doxygen-chm --disable-doxygen-chi --disable-doxygen-html --disable-doxygen-ps --disable-doxygen-pdf --disable-core-docs --disable-manpages --disable-xmltoman --disable-tests --disable-compat-libdns_sd --disable-compat-howl --with-distro=none --with-xml=expat
```

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 15.04 with avahi git head and it doesn't seem to link to libssp.  Can you check the ldd output and see if it is included there? Maybe it doesn't show up in ldd.  I would also ensure you did make clean before.  My main thought is that perhaps one of the avahi dependencies is actually loading libssp.

Comment: You're right. one of the avahi dependencies is actually loading libssp.I made a clean and have returned to recompile and it works!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my correct comment into an answer;

Most likely one of the dependencies is compiled against ssp, rather than avahi-daemon itself.  I would check all of the dependencies (and avahi-daemon) with the 'ldd' tool.